# QUOTES ON ASP.NET - SQLDataSource - FilterExpression

Tags: asp.net

hI Experts,

I'm getting the error below when I pass serach filed with quote e.g. abb's

```
The expression contains an invalid string constant: '.
```

is there anyway I can resolve this? Also if you could send me a link on all the functions avaialbe for filterexpression such as Replace, Cast etc will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having this issue. This code below fixed the issue:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DS.SelectCommand = 
      "SELECT ReportName, ReportType, 
       FROM Table 
       WHERE ReportName LIKE @param 
       ORDER BY ReportType Desc";
   DS.SelectParameters.Add("Param", searchTxtBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
   DS.DataBind();
   ListView1.DataBind();               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ' with two single ' the query works.

Comment: can i do this within expression or javascript? I prefer to do in expression if possible

Comment: You can use this anywhere use replace method and replace [' with two single ' ], normally this issue comes in sql query.

Comment: Ok you may need to show me. if i have this on filterExpression:Name LIKE '%{0}%'  (in visual studio designer). How can we replace the {0} parameter? I tried replace and complained replace is not function.

Answer (score 0):

In SqlDataSource add

> onfiltering="SqlDataSource1_Filtering"

Code Behind Function:

```
 protected void SqlDataSource1_Filtering(object sender, SqlDataSourceFilteringEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression.Replace("{0}", e.ParameterValues[0].ToString().Replace("'","''" );

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @saurabh, added the code behind DS_Filtering(....) but i get this error message CS1061: 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'DS_Filtering' and no extension method 'GDS_Filtering' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)